# barcodescanner in react-native for both ios/android

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

Hai i am trying for barcode scanner in react-native, I used react-native-camera it shows some errors which i mentioned in it https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/242.
is there any module for qr code reader in react-native, for android is used react-native-barcodescanner, It working in android, Like this is any module is there, Please give me suggestions. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have created a project to combine `react-native-camera` (for iOS) and `react-native-barcodescanner` (for Android), published at https://github.com/applean/react-native-barcode-scanner-universal . You can read https://github.com/applean/react-native-barcode-scanner-universal#install to know how to install and use it.

It just provided same module to use, but has some different details.

Comment: react-native-barcodescanner  reading only QR codes. Any workaround  ?

Answer (score 0):

It is now available with Expo BarCodeScanner https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/